# How to sum every nth row with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I sum every nth row, without having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys
So I am aware of a formula like this

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW($A$1:$A$250),2)=0,$A$1:$A$250,0))
```

But that requires that you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula.

How can I do this, without having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) function
Like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(ROW($A$1:$A$250)-ROW($A$1),2)=0)*($A$1:$A$250))
```

Comment: Would you add an explanation as to how this works?